# adjust height of frame automatically to window size

Tags: html

In `html`, is there a way to adjust the size of the `frame` to vary according to the `browser` window size?

For example, note `height=667`. Is there semantics to say: Adjust your frame size as the user resizes the window to the window size.

```
<iframe src="https://sslecal2.forexprostools.com?columns=exc_flags,exc_currency,exc_importance,exc_actual,exc_forecast,exc_previous&features=datepicker,timezone&countries=25,32,6,37,72,22,17,39,14,10,35,43,56,36,110,11,26,12,4,5&calType=week&timeZone=8&lang=1" width="650" height="667" .....
```

Comment: Have you tried `height="100%"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<body style="margin:0px;padding:0px;overflow:hidden">
    <iframe src="http://www.youraddress.com" frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;height:100%;width:100%;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
</body>
```

This would be one alternative. Hope it helps!